# ActiveAdmin association doesn't update its attributes in save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, activeadmin, formtastic

I can't get ActiveAdmin to save the associated model when the initial model is saved.

I have two models that look like this:

```
# app/models/account.rb
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :endpoint, inverse_of :account, class_name: 'Abcd::Endpoint'
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :endpoint

  delegate :access_key, to: :endpoint
end

# app/models/abcd/endpoint.rb
class Abcd::Endpoint < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :account_id, :access_key

  belongs_to :account
end
```

My ActiveAdmin file looks like:

```
# app/admin/account.rb
Activeadmin.register Account do

  form do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :name
    end

    f.inputs title: 'endpoints', for: [:endpoint. f.object.endpoint || Endpoint.new] do |nested_form|
      nested_form.input :access_key,
        label: 'Access Key',
        as: :string
    end
    f.actions
  end

  show do |account|
    row 'endpoint has access_key' do
      account.access_key
    end
  end
end
```

When I click on "Update Account" the Account gets updated but the Endpoint 
model doesn't get updated.  It appears that the Endpoint attributes aren't 
being sent to the Endpoint model.

Does anyone know how to get the Endpoint model to get updated with its 
attributes or what I need to fix?

Comment: shoudn't it be  nested_form.input instead  nested.form.input

Comment: I'm sorry, it was a typo on my part.  What I had in the app/admin/account.rb file code was nested_form.input.  Updated the question.

Comment: What happens if you replace `Endpoint.new` with `f.object.build_endpoint`?

Comment: I tried that and the endpoint instance's attributes still don't get updated.

Answer (score 0):

give it a try

```
form do |f|
    f.inputs "Account" do
      f.input :name
    end

    f.inputs do
      f.has_one :endpoint, inverse_of :account, class_name: 'Abcd::Endpoint' do |nested_form|
         nested_form.input :access_key,
         nested_form.label('Access key')
      end
    end
  f.actions
end
```

Comment: This gives me two problems.  1)  it errors on inverse_of which I can fix by adding a colon to as "inverse_of:", 2)  undefined method "has_one", which I can't figure out how to fix.

Comment: @JamesTesta actually i had seen f.has_many from http://www.activeadmin.info/docs/5-forms.html, so i thought has_one should also work.

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/59#issuecomment-21467793

Comment: I tried this but associations attributes still didn't update.